# Keep efimeral external IP but disable external HTTP request and keep internals on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, firewall

I have an App on GCE that needs to have "internet" connection, but I don't want it to be accessible externally, but only by its internal IP (HTTP) by others service (others GCE and Cloud Run instances on serverless VPC).

How can I disable the external without removing the external IP? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two implied firewall rules in gcp with lowest priority. You cannot delete these.

- Allow all egress traffic (this will allow your instance to access the
  internet)
- Deny all ingress traffic (this blocks your instance to be accessible from anywhere)

Solution - You can create a firewall rule to allow ingress traffic only from internal vpc network on TCP port 80.

1. Select your instance and click on Edit.
2. In Networking column, remove http-server and https-server tags if present and add your own tag e.g "my-app" and save. *We will allow http traffic in our own firewall rule.*
   [image]
3. Go to VPC network. Select Firewall. Create a firewall rule to allow ingress traffic with target tag as "my-app" and source as CIDR IP range of your vpc network or subnet with tcp port 80. This rule will **allow only internal HTTP traffic** only from vpc network.

[image]

Comment: Thank! Diggin a little in the firewall, found that a rule "default-allow-internal" already exist, but I'm using VPC serverless (with Cloud Run) and it have another range

Comment: Cool. [Maybe this will help](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/ingress)

Comment: @CNK - edit your question and include that detail. Using VPC connectors and Cloud Run makes a big difference in understanding your problem.